# Changing a Date/Time Value by hours using process builder

Tags: process-builder

I have object 1 "Classes and Events" on which I want to store start and end times for the times a course or event would run outside our work ordered day. The work ordered day is 9am to 5pm. Certain courses/events run from within the work ordered day and overlap 5pm, eg. 3pm to 6pm.

We capture attendances on a sign in sheet for our members which is then entered onto the "Attendance" object. The  attendance is recorded between the Work Ordered Day and afterwards. The hours cannot overlap.

We have an "Internal events" object that has a look up to the "Classes and Events" object to standardise data entry. When an Internal event is recorded, a process populates reporting fields on the Internal event record.

We have an "Attendee" object which is a master-detail child to "Internal events". When an Attendee is recorded as attending an Internal Event, if a check box "create attendances" has been ticked on the "Classes and Events" objects, an "Attendance" record is created.

I would like to use start time and end time fields to create a record with start date/time and end date/time fields. There is a difficulty however in that the Time fields and the Date/Time fields are a view of GMT data held in the field. I have tried but failed to pull the correct time for 6 months of the year because of this. See this post: https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000t5CAQAY.

To add to this, I would like to create the attendance record from the internal events record according to the time fields on the classes and events object.

So Apex seems to be the only route is this correct? Can I possibly achieve this through Process Builder?